# Are the ":" or "/" in SDP values for attributes tokens by themselves with spaces optionally allowed around them?

Tags: webrtc, sip, sdp

In SDP, colon(':') and slash('/') are used in many attribute values (both the standard and a= extensions). Here are just a few of them:

```
  b=AS:41
  a=rtpmap:96 AMR-WB/16000/1
  a=fmtp:96 mode-change-capability=2; max-red=80
```

I want to know (both for parsing and generating SDP), if space is allowed around them. All examples point to not having a space around them. I think Section 9 of RFC 4566 which gives the grammar for SDP is not clear about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, that usually, SDP don't like whitespace. The first rule from rfc4566 is not answering your question, but it's a start:

```
An SDP session description consists of a number of lines of text of
the form:

  <type>=<value>

where <type> MUST be exactly one case-significant character and
<value> is structured text whose format depends on <type>.  In
general, <value> is either a number of fields delimited by a single
space character or a free format string, and is case-significant
unless a specific field defines otherwise.  Whitespace MUST NOT be
used on either side of the "=" sign.
```

Let's start with the bandwidth parameter where the definition exists in rfc4566

```
bandwidth-fields =    *(%x62 "=" bwtype ":" bandwidth CRLF)
; sub-rules of 'b='
bwtype =              token
token =               1*(token-char)
token-char =          %x21 / %x23-27 / %x2A-2B / %x2D-2E / %x30-39
                     / %x41-5A / %x5E-7E
bandwidth =           1*DIGIT
```

From the above:

- there is no whitespace allowed in **bwtype** because **%x20** is not part of **token-char**
- there is no whitespace allowed in **bandwidth** because it contains only **DIGIT**.
- there is no whitespace on left or right of ":", otherwise, the specification would use something like **bwtype SP ":" SP bandwidth**

For rtpmap, in RFC4566 Section 6, the definition of rtpmap is here:

```
a=rtpmap:<payload type> <encoding name>/<clock rate> [/<encoding
  parameters>]
```

This seems to introduce the requirement for a space between clock rate and encoding parameter (but it's NOT BNF format!!!). However, there is an [errata here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/eid5183) which reports that was an error.

According to my experience, it is not allowed to have space in rtpmap execpt between **payload type** and the payload definition.

For rtpmap, you may also check the newer ietf document [rfc4566bis](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-mmusic-rfc4566bis-37#section-6.6) which provides a BNF definition for rtpmap, and this one is clearly without space:

```
rtpmap-value = payload-type SP encoding-name
   "/" clock-rate [ "/" encoding-params ]
payload-type = zero-based-integer
encoding-name = token
clock-rate = integer
encoding-params = channels
channels = integer
```

fmtp is more tricky, but the definition in newer [rfc4566bis](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-mmusic-rfc4566bis-37#section-6.6) is allowing spaces in **byte-string** BNF definition:

```
fmtp-value = fmt SP format-specific-params
format-specific-params = byte-string
byte-string =         1*(%x01-09/%x0B-0C/%x0E-FF)
                      ;any byte except NUL, CR, or LF
```

Also, from experience, some rfc are using space around **";"** and other are not. I'm not able to find the exact reason, but it may be related to the fact that spaces are allowed in Content-Type HTML header. To read more about this, you may check [rfc4855](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4855) and [rfc2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045).

Comment: So unless there is an explicit SP specified in the grammar, one can safely (or almost so) assume that there is no space?

Comment: If the grammar doesn't allow space, of course there is not! Problems comes only when you don't find the grammar...