# Must a SDP line start with the attribute character or can it start with Whitespace? RFC is not clear

Tags: sdp

RFC 4566 is the controlling RFC for SDP syntax.
It states in [Section 5 - SDP Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4566#section-5) that:

> ```
>    An SDP session description consists of a number of lines of text of
>    the form:
>
>       <type>=<value>
>
>    where <type> MUST be exactly one case-significant character and
>    <value> is structured text whose format depends on <type>.  In
>    general, <value> is either a number of fields delimited by a single
>    space character or a free format string, and is case-significant
>    unless a specific field defines otherwise.  Whitespace MUST NOT be
>    used on either side of the "=" sign.
> ```

However, nowhere is it clear whether there can be whitespace before the case-significant character.
Section 9.0 which provides the BNF grammar is also ambiguous on this issue. All SDP entriess I have seen appear to start the attribute lines from the first position but is whitespace allowed at the start of an SDP entry is the question.

The answer provided to a somewhat similar but definitely different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59483948/are-the-or-in-sdp-values-for-attributes-tokens-by-themselves-with-spaces) I had asked earlier sheds some light but is not definitive on this particular issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces before the case-significant character is not allowed. The BNF/ABNF does not show that you can add spaces before the lines defined in `session-description`. They even explicit say which letter you have to use like `v=...`.

Comment: "The BNF/ABNF does not show that you can add spaces before the lines" True. But it does not state otherwise either as definitely as it states   about not having spaces around the "="  I am looking for a definite reference. If one is not provided, I will accept your answer later.

Comment: @asinix The BNF/ABNF shows the syntax you can use and it says that none of the lines, which can be added, can start with a whitespace. They must start with one of the letters defined in the individual lines like `i` for the `information-field` line. If a space would be allowed it would be listed with something like `SP` in the BNF/ABNF.